# svg dinamico con cambio de color

Tags: css, svg

Estoy obteniendo un listado de archivos svg para el manejo del menu lateral, los estoy renderizando utilizando `object`.

```
<object data="http://..." type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Mi problema es que no puedo cambiar el fill desde mi archivo `css`

```
path {
 fill: red !important;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe de que manera puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Si optas por utilizar objetos necesitas utilizar filtros para cambiar el color del fill: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/YMmEvw Una opción mucho mejor sería utilizar inline svg - o sea elementos svg dentro del DOM

Comment: @enxaneta lo pude solucionar utilizando filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacerlo es utilizando filter como lo ha mensionado @enxaneta en su comentario.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/YMmEvw)